# Evaluate $\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{n\pi}_0 \text{sgn}(\sin(x)) \text{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I would like to calculate $\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{n\pi}_0 \text{sgn}(\sin(x))\text{d}x$ for $n=1,2,3...$. $\text{sgn}(x)=1$ if $x\geq0$ and $\text{sgn}(x)=-1$ if $x<0$.

My way: So for 
$$x \in [2,3]\cup[4,5]\cup[6,7]\cup...$$

we have that $\text{sgn}(\sin(x))=1$ so hence the integral is $\int^{n\pi}_0 \text{d} x=\frac{n\pi}{\pi}=n$.

So same with the other partition of $x$ and I get $-n$ and hence the integral is $0$. But this is probably wrong, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean for $x\in [2,3]\cup[4,5]\cup\dots$ instead of $n$?

Edit: Brian is correct below, it should be $2\pi,3\pi$, etc.

Comment: It doesn't really make much sense to say $n \in [2,3] \cup [4,5], \cup [6,7] \cup \ldots$.  I'm guessing you meant $x \in [0,\pi] \cup [2\pi,3\pi] \cup [4\pi,5\pi]\cup \cdots$ but even this has an error in that it doesn't take $n$ into consideration.

Comment: @Keshav actually yes, that's what i meant

Comment: Try computing it for multiple low values of $n$, and you'll be able see where the issue is I think.

Comment: Consider when $n$ is odd, and when $n$ is even.

Comment: Sketch the graph of the function $f(x)={\rm sgn}(\sin x)$ and you should be able to see that the integral is $1$ for odd $n$ and $0$ for even.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1$

$$\int_0^\pi sgn(\sin(x))dx=\int_0^\pi dx=\pi$$

for $n=2$,

$$\int_0^{2\pi}sgn(\sin(x))dx=1-1=0$$

thus
If $n=2k$, we find $0$

If $n=2k+1$ it gives $1$.